# Pycharm with virtualenv, use Shelve module: No module named _bsddb

Tags: python, virtualenv, pycharm, berkeley-db, shelve

I receive the error "No module named _bsddb".
I installed berkeley-db4 using Brew.
I load up the virtualenv and use "pip install bsddb3 --install-option="--berkeley-db='/usr/local/opt/berkeley-db4'" but I can't get passed this in any way I can think of:

```
Collecting bsddb3
  Using cached bsddb3-6.1.1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Can't find a local Berkeley DB installation.
    (suggestion: try the --berkeley-db=/path/to/bsddb option)

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/g6/j96dym1x0jx9ydrdkfs4dhnr0000gn/T/pip-build-676fDz/bsddb3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably OS X only, because the shipped Python has something broken regarding berkeley-db and/or bsddb.

The solution:

1. Install brew and use brew to install python
2. After this 'which python' should pount to '/usr/local/bin/python'
3. Create a new virtualenv using Terminal OUTSIDE OF PYCHARM
4. In Pycharm's Project Interpreter settings choose 'Add Local'
5. Select the python bin inside your virtualenv directory